# Stop and return object within function without reporting error

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to return an object if an if statement is TRUE from a function `foo` within a  parent function `bar`, and not execute following code in `bar`; or if FALSE, execute the following code in `bar`. In the function `bar2` below I can test the output of `foo` and then execute more code in `bar2` if the output of `foo` is NULL. However, in trying to reduce lines of code used, I want to know if I can somehow prevent "howdy" from printing in the `bar` function if the if statement in the function `foo` is TRUE.  `stop` would do it but is signals an error, which is not what is happening here. Basically I'm looking for an equivalent of `stop` but returning an object w/o error.

```
foo <- function(x){
  if(x < 10){
    "hello world"
  } else
  { NULL }
}

bar <- function(y){
 foo(y)
 "howdy"
}

bar2 <- function(y){
  out <- foo(y)
  if(!is.null(out)){
    out
  } else
  {
    "howdy"
  }
}

bar(5)
[1] "howdy"

bar2(5)
[1] "hello world"
```

Comment: You could make `foo` take an `else_value = NULL` argument and it will return that value in its else part. Then `bar` can just be calling `foo(y, else_value = "howdy")`.

Comment: Ah, good thinking. What I left out for simplicity sake is that the one line of code printing "howdy" in my actual situation is about 10 lines of code. Otherwise, that solution would work

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you can put that code in a `{...}` block, or maybe nicer, put the code in a `z` function and do `foo(y, else_value = z())`. Note that `z()` will only be run if necessary, e.g. I tried `foo(1, else_value = {Sys.sleep(10), "howdy"})` and it returned `"hello world"` immediately.

Comment: Good point about passing a function call or `{...}` block. That's a good work around for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason `bar` is not working, is because of scope. You have to perform some form of check in `bar`; **this is unavoidable**.

What you might be looking for is `return` instead of stop:

```
bar <- function(y){
 if (!is.null(foo(y))) {
    return("hello world")   # breaks out of the function
 }
 print("this will never print when foo doesn't return NULL")
 "howdy"     # ending part, so it would be returned only if foo(y) != "h..."
}
```

Extra:

I am not sure if you got this part, but the reason your functions work is because you implicitly *return* something when something is called, while it is the ending part of a function.

E.g.:

```
test <- function() {
 "hello world"
  a <- "hello world"
}
```

Running `test()` won't return the "hello world" it would otherwise, because the last thing ran is not a call.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's what I'm looking for. Tried your functions, but they key is that I want the line `foo(y)` in the function `bar` to return the result and not execute the next line(s) if the if statement is TRUE. Right, NULL doesn't have to be returned, it could be something else. This is a silly example just to keep it short.

Comment: The first line now adresses it. This is not possible!

Comment: Read about scope; an inner function cannot control anything in the outer function (except return an object).

Comment: So yea, catch the thing from `foo` in `bar`, and depending on the result you can use `return` to skip the rest of everything in the `bar` function.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry for the vague explanations, but I hope it helped! Feel free to continue asking!